# Can't read file in Android - C# & Unity3d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

EDIT:
**Already solved! I've changed that if to:**

```
string written_path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Data/test.mp4";
               if (System.IO.File.Exists(written_path))
```

---

I'm downloading a file with WWW.
It downloads to this path (this is the path that appears when I go to the details of the file in the Samsung Galaxy file explorer):

file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.MyName.Video/files/Data/test.mp4

The problem is that I have an If clause, when that does not exist, I have to download the file.
That works, but when I already have the file, the if it's still false

The file exists, and in my manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

My If looks like this:

```
       case "Example":


                    if (System.IO.File.Exists("file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.MyName.Video/files/Data/test.mp4"))
                    {
                        Application.LoadLevel("Example");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StartCoroutine(DownloadStreamingVideoAndLoad("http://exampleweb.es/test.mp4"));
                    }

       break;
```

And this is the code I have for downloading the file:

```
   if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Data") == false)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Data");

        string write_path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Data" + strURL.Substring(strURL.LastIndexOf("/"));
        Debug.Log(write_path);

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(write_path, www.bytes);

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Already solved! I changed that if to: `string written_path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Data/test.mp4";


                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(written_path))`